# Header/Footer Issue in New Document

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I use Word 2003 - when I create a new document using File > New, the header and footer sections of the document are not visible.

If I subsequently attempt to edit the header/footer using View > Header and Footer, even if I type nothing in and close the header/footer floating toolbar immediately, the header and footer remain visible thereafter until I close the document. If I open the saved document, the header and footer are visible.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > View` and mark the check box near "White space between pages" option. Click OK, test it and tell us if it solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: Hmmm. Did not work for me. The box was already checked. Unchecking and re-checking (as well as exit the program and run again) did no good either.